# Very weird behavior when adding wcf reference

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, service-reference

Ok, so I'm really frustrated with what is going on right now.  In Visual Studio 2013, I updated the service reference to my WCF service and now the objects are gone!  Everything was working fine yesterday.  Has anyone experienced this before?

Here is what I've done to troubleshoot and the results.

1. Checked the WSDL and the objects are there.
2. Added a service reference to the SAME service on a different project in the same solution and all of the objects come through fine.
3. Deleted the service reference from the original project, saved the solution, closed the solution, deleted all the files associated with the service reference, opened the solution back up, re-added the service reference and **still no objects**.
4. Restored the entire project from yesterday (when it was last working) and the objects return.  As soon as I update the reference, bam, they're gone.

I'm convinced that there is nothing wrong on the service end because I can add a reference to that service in another project and it works as expected.

This is happening in my UI project so I'd REALLY like to not have to start a new project and move everything over.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I had a service reference to the same service in another project that was named the same.  I'm not sure if this screwed something up to begin with or not...

Any thoughts?

Thanks!
John

Comment: did yiu Consider generating using svcutil?

Comment: @Dhawalk - I didn't try the svcutil route, but I'm sure that would have worked too.  I am working heavily on the service and ui interaction so it's much more convenient to just be able to right click + update service reference.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Consider swapping away from using the wcf as a web reference and use it directly through a contract assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out how to fix it, although I'm not sure it deserves to be added as an answer.  My edit above got me thinking and I removed the service reference and any references to the other project that referenced the same service.  I made sure all references were removed from all files (configs, project files, etc.).  Saved the solution, checked in all changes and deletions (just to make sure nothing was lingering around) and deleted any files related to the original service reference.  I open the solution back up and re-added the service reference viola, it's there with all of the object references!  I guess it did have something to do with that other project...

Now to see if I can remember what I was supposed to be working on in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

3rd Party dll blocking the generation of objects - perhaps by including an existing project in solution.

Unchecking 'Reuse types in all referenced assemblies' when configuring the service solved the issue.